# Automate IAR Compile, Link and execute from Python

Tags: python-3.x, iar

I am a starter in Python but in case of my project, i have to develop an application to manage Compile, Link and Execution about IAR Embedded Workbench from Python.

I don't really now how to perform and how to begin, if someone can explain me how to do for the beginning.

Comment: I have two follow up questions. First, do you have an existing EW project or is it a set of files you need to compile? Second, do you really need the actual workbench or is it the compiler tool-chain you want?

Comment: Hi Johan ! No indeed, i don't have any existing EW project. The goal would be to automate the Compile, Link and Execution with the load of all my C existing program in the flash memory.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to build a project from the command line is the usage of the IAR command line tool :-)

```
<installation dir>\common\bin\IarBuild.exe test.ewp Debug
```

To use this, you must first create a working EW project from your code an than you could directly execute the build.

If you don't want to create a EW project you could also call the compiler and linker on your own

```
<installation dir>\arm\bin\iccarm.exe <source-file> <options>
<installation dir>\arm\bin\ilinkarm.exe -f options.xcl
```

But if you do so, you have to take care of all the options and configurations for you project.